# Sort Result Set in Data View by Multiple Columns

Tags: datagrip

In prior versions of DataGrip (presumed earlier than *2021.1*), result sets within the Data View pane allowed ad-hoc sorting across multiple columns by clicking on column headers in sequence to assign a custom sort order. This functionality is documented in the [Data Editor Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/table-editor.html). Since the release of version *2021.1*, clicking multiple columns in sequence resorts the entire result set by the most recently clicked column header only.

Using the following statement as an example yields a result set with 120 date values spanning 4 months, where *month_start_date* is repeated for *calendar_date* values that occur within the same month:

```
SELECT month_start_date
     , calendar_date
FROM calendar
WHERE month_start_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-04-01'
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

When the *month_start_date* column header is clicked, the entire result set is sorted based on *month_start_date*:

[image: data_view_sorted_by_col_1]

When the *calendar_date* header is subsequently clicked (following clicking the *month_start_date* column header), the entire result set is re-sorted based only on the values of *calendar_date*:

[image: data_view_sorted_by_col_2]

Is there a way to sort by multiple columns in version *2021.1*, or has this functionality been intentionally removed?

Comment: Can you please refer to where exactly accumulating sorting is documented here? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/table-editor.html

Comment: I was referring to the screenshot shown within the **Show Options Menu** section, which displays accumulated sorting, however you are correct that the documentation in this same section only refers to unchecking the `SORT BY` option. The guidance you have provided in your answer is quite clear though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in [release notes](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/whatsnew/2021-1/#version-2021-1-data-editor), from 2021.1 accumulating sorting should be performed via `Alt/Opt+Click.`